# How to filter array in map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have following loop

```
response.result.forEach(item => {
                  this.tableModel.push(
                   new FolderSearchModel().map(item, this.resources)
                    );
            });
```

I want to place if statement so I could change/format mapped value eg.:

```
 if(item.element == "aa"){
item.element = "AA"
}
```

Comment: Ideal way would be using a `.reduce`, however you can do `.filter().map()`

Comment: So...why can't you use that `if` statement? What is the problem?

Comment: @Rajesh I don't have .filter() function on FolderSearchModel()

Comment: how you have written the `.map` method on `FolderSearchModel`?

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything in your map function.  That seems to be the issue.  Also, you are confusing the way that Array.map and Array.filter work.

Array.filter(function()=>{return item.element === "AA"}) would return an array, where all items were filtered out except those that meet the requirement (ie, does the item.element === "AA")

You're not really filtering, so much as changing only certain elements.  You do it like this.

```
FolderSearchModel().map(function (item, this.resources) {
   if(item.element == "aa"){
     item.element = "AA"
   }
  return item
})
```

This code will only work if FolderSearcModel() returns an array for you to map over.  Map takes the item, allows you to change it (or not, based on your conditional logic) and return it back to the index.